# Array within an Array to single Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var value = [{
    "rowid": "one, two, three"
}, {
    "rowid": "four"
}]

var selected = value.map(function(varId) {
    return varId.rowid.toString();
});
console.log(selected);
console.log(selected.length);
```

The Output I'm getting is

```
["one, two, three", "four"]
2
```

But I'm expecting

```
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
4
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Just a quick note - what you have is an array of objects, not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Not sure about syntax but the logic should be something like: console.log(selected.split(',').length);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var value = [{ "rowid": "one, two, three" }, { "rowid": "four" }],
    selected = value.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.rowid.split(', '));
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(selected, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment it is array of objects not array of arrays 
anyway try `return varId.rowid.toString().split(',');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sel = value.map(function(varId) {
    var rowId = varId.rowid.toString();
    var splitted = rowId.split(",");    
    return splitted;
});
var arrayOfStrings = [].concat.apply([], sel);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
   arrayOfStrings[i] = arrayOfStrings[i].trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split your first string by the comma (', '),
afterwards flatten the multidimensional array.

```
var value = [{
    "rowid": "one, two, three"
}, {
    "rowid": "four"
}];

var selected = value.map(function(varId) {
    return varId.rowid.toString().split(', ');
});    
// [ [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ], [ 'four' ] ]
selected = [].concat.apply([], selected);
// [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]
console.log(selected);
console.log(selected.length);
```